# Offering all authentication mechanisms in an ASP.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on

Mine is a web product (delivered to a browser), being built on ASP.Net (Framework 4.0).

Most customers seek Single Sign On, such that their users should directly logon to the application on its invocation with the Windows or Active Directory login, they're using. Some other customers want the application to accept form based login credentials. So basically my web application should be able to adjust (configured) based on the customer's requirement. Their may be claims based authentication is some stray cases as well. I'd like to know the best way to achieve this in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

.NET open auth is your friend.
http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Then, there's active directory/LDAP:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#35

And your own provider + WinForms should be clear.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Further, can you suggest something from within Microsoft offerings?

Comment: Single sign on is for multiple applications on the same machine. You need to implement all methods and make it configurable in web.config. I gave you the AD method (updated link to point to the correct location in page).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the long gap between my communications. Basically I am looking for a .net based framework that will enable my product to 'use' any authentication mechanism. Does such a framework exist? For example, I am using OleDB for connecting to a bunch of data sources without having to change my application code ... wherein all I need is OleDB providers for respective data sources. I hope the analogy is clear.